# KVM-switch without installing drivers?

Tags: kvm-switch

I have never used KVM before, so my question could sounds naive: is it possible to find KVM-switch, that could work without software drivers?

"Active KVM-switch" there I mean those that can suppress "unplug events for USB keyboard and mouse", but the switching is done still by "pressing the button on the KVM" (so there are no need to have software installed on computer to handle switching).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most KVM switches don't require drivers; they emulate normal HID and DDC connections so that the computer doesn't know any different, and detect key presses (<kbd>ScrLck</kbd> twice on the ones I've used) to switch.

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to find KVM-switch, that could work without software drivers?

Yes. Infact most don't need drives. They are very simple and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all new generation kvm switches work without requiring software installation. These kvm switchers comes in multiple sizes and types and can also be casacded to serve a higher number of servers.